# Custom optional parameter in Rails server command

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use custom optional parameters in Rails server command like this or with some variants regarding the format of the optional parameters:

```
rails s --foo bar
```

Probably I would be using the optparse gem. How can I set something like this?

Comment: Simplest way would be to pass in ENV variables instead of optional parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would choose the ENV variables as suggested in comments.

But if you need options you could edit `bin/rails` executable and add (just after the shabang `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` ):

```
require 'optparse'
options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner = "Usage: example.rb [options]"
  opts.on("--foo", "Foo mode") do |v|
    p '> Foo option'
  end
end.parse!
```

Then remember to execute with:

```
bundle exec rails s --foo
```